# C# Monodroid/Xamarin - List Implementation Differences for GingerBread through to JellyBean

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-4.2-jelly-bean

**Scenario**

- I want to implement a list for my Android app, written in C# using Monodroid/Xamarin.
- I'd like the app to run on GingerBread 2.3.6 (as well as the latest versions of JellyBean).
- The list functionality should be similar to that of the WhatsApp "open chats" list (i.e. you have an image on the left of the row cell, some text in the middle of the row cell, and a button on the right of the row cell.)
- I'm very well versed in programming iOS application in C#, and am now moving to Android.
- I'm aware that there is fragmentation across the different versions of Android, but I can't be certain of the difference in implementing a list iteself across the different versions.

**Questions**

- Is there a difference in list implementations in GingerBread 2.3.6 vs. JellyBean 4.x?
- Will it be much easier to code a list implementation in JellyBean, rather than in GingerBread?
- If there are two different methods of implementing a list across the different versions, can each be implemented programmatically, purely in code?

**Things to keep In Mind**

- I would preferably like to create the list purely in code, programmatically (without using any sort of XML/XAML or interface building tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the official Android docs for [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), then you will be able to see which methods got added at which API level. To tell you the truth, nothing fundamentally has changed since API level 1. So just get started with your code.